# RealmMigrationNeededException when adding new schema with addRealmObjectField

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, realm-migration

I want to add a new schema to my DB referencing another new schema.

Here are the models:

```
open class Code(
    var name: String? = null,
    var code: String? = null
) : RealmObject()

open class Foo(
    var codes: RealmList<Code> = RealmList()
) : RealmObject()
```

And the migration:

```
val codeSchema = schema.create("Code")
        .addField("name", String::class.java)
        .addField("code", String::class.java)

schema.create("Foo")
    .addRealmObjectField("codes", codeSchema)
```

But this crashes with the following error:

```
io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Migration is required due to the following errors:
    - Property 'Foo.codes' has been changed from '<Code>' to 'array<Code>'.
```

Because these are both *new* models, I don't know why it tells me that something "has been changed".

How can I add those two models correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it. I need to use `addRealmListField()` instead of `addRealmObjectField()` because it references a list and not a single object.